# React router is not reloading page when url matches the same route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have following route. When I'm at `/createtest` page and doing `history.push(/createtest/some-test-id)` as it matches the same route component, it is not reloaded. ***Is there any smart solution***? Or I need to check `match` params and implement logic to reload?

(react 16, router v4)

```
<Route path="/createtest/:testid?/:type?/:step?/:tab?" render={(props) => <CreateTest user={user} {...props}/>}/>
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51751075/api-call-after-reloading-same-route-via-react-router/51751268#51751268) answer your question?

Comment: So reading match params and manually reloading is a solution I knew as I mentioned in the question. Looking for smart solutions.

Comment: You need to use `exact` props.
refer to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could give the URL parameters as `key` to the component so that an entirely new component will be created when a URL parameter changes.

```js
<Route
  path="/createtest/:testid?/:type?/:step?/:tab?"
  render={props => {
    const {
      match: {
        params: { testid, type, step, tab }
      }
    } = props;
    return (
      <CreateTest
        key={`testid=${testid}&type=${type}&step=${step}&tab=${tab}`}
        user={user}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: This is a very very smart solution. I'll accept it once I implement it and I see it works (cause react 16 might not refresh on basis of `key` ). But pretty smart though

Comment: Absolute genius. So simple, yet so elegant. It worked

Comment: Could someone explain the syntax here? Its an anonym function fed to the render property of the route, that returns the jsx, and we somehow take just the needed url params and make a key prop for the component, right? But how does that const {} = props thing work?

Comment: @rayaqin It's called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). It's essentially just sugar for `const testid = props.match.params.testid, type = props.match.params.type, ...`

Comment: Tip, you have to remove the "component" prop (if you have one) for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const Reloadable = (props) => {
    const { location } = props
    const [key, setKey] = useState(location.key)

    if (location.key !== key) {
        setTimeout(() => setKey(location.key), 0)
        return null
    }
    return <>{props.children}</>
}

<Route path="/" exact render={({ history, location }) => (
    <Reloadable location={location}>
        <SomeComponent />
    </Reloadable>)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might help solve your problem

```
<Route key={'notReloadableRoute'} ... />
```

(static key, like a regular string)

Answer (score -1):

See this doc.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

> The exact param comes into play when
>   you have multiple paths that have similar names:
>
> For example, imagine we had a Users component that displayed a list of
>   users. We also have a CreateUser component that is used to create
>   users. The url for CreateUsers should be nested under Users. So our
>   setup could look something like this:
>
> Now the problem here, when we go to
>   http://app.com/users the router will go through all of our defined
>   routes and return the FIRST match it finds. So in this case, it would
>   find the Users route first and then return it. All good.
>
> But, if we went to http://app.com/users/create, it would again go
>   through all of our defined routes and return the FIRST match it finds.
>   React router does partial matching, so /users partially matches
>   /users/create, so it would incorrectly return the Users route again!
>
> The exact param disables the partial matching for a route and makes
>   sure that it only returns the route if the path is an EXACT match to
>   the current url.
>
> So in this case, we should add exact to our Users route so that it
>   will only match on /users:

Comment: Doesn't work . May be I failed to explain the problem,  but this doesn't fix the issue .